# Truncated incorrect INTEGER value while insert into temporary table mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

> 0 72  17:37:20    call new_procedure  Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect
>   INTEGER value: '_3_ELECTRICITY BILL_3.pdf'    0.140 sec

**note:** `3_ELECTRICITY BILL_3.pdf` value contains in `tbl_AccountOpeningForm` table  in `AttachmentName` column

but if i removed `having clause` from query it work fine.

```
tbl_AccountOpeningForm
CustNo          VARCHAR(80)
AttachmentName  VARCHAR(100)



-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN


drop table  if exists tblReport;
 create temporary table tblReport
 (  
  CustNo varchar(80)  
 )  ;


 insert into tblReport (CustNo) 
 select CustNo 
 from tbl_AccountOpeningForm 
 group by CustNo 
 having COUNT(case when LTRIM(RTRIM(AttachmentName))='' then null else AttachmentName end)!=
 COUNT(case when LTRIM(RTRIM(AttachmentName))!='' then null else AttachmentName end) limit 10000000;
 select * from  tblReport;


END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try phrasing the logic like this:

```
 having SUM(LTRIM(RTRIM(AttachmentName)) <> '') <> SUM(LTRIM(RTRIM(AttachmentName)) = '')
limit 10000000;
```

MySQL is usually pretty smart about the return type from a `case` expression.  The error message suggests that it is getting confused.  If this is the problem, then the simplified logic should fix it.